# How to batch delete the redis keys from local machine and through a jump machine inside kubernetes cluster?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, terminal, xargs

I need to delete some keys in my redis cluster which can only be accessed from a jump machine deployed in the kubernetes cluster.

So if I know the key I can delete it by the following command without problem:

```
➜ kubectl exec -it jump-machine -- /usr/local/bin/redis-cli -c -h redis-cluster-host DEL "the-key"
(interger) 1
```

But if I want to do it in batch then it gives output 0 which means not deleted:

```
➜ kubectl exec -it jump-machine -- /usr/local/bin/redis-cli -c -h redis-cluster-host --scan --pattern "*the-key-pattern*" | xargs -L 1 kubectl exec -it jump-machine -- /usr/local/bin/redis-cli -c -h redis-cluster-host -c DEL

Unable to use a TTY - input is not a terminal or the right kind of file
0
Unable to use a TTY - input is not a terminal or the right kind of file
0
Unable to use a TTY - input is not a terminal or the right kind of file
0
Unable to use a TTY - input is not a terminal or the right kind of file
0
Unable to use a TTY - input is not a terminal or the right kind of file
0
Unable to use a TTY - input is not a terminal or the right kind of file
0
Unable to use a TTY - input is not a terminal or the right kind of file
0
```

I'm quite new about using the `xargs`, and I can't tell where is wrong.

I tried debug it with the following command, it gives all the keys without issue:

```
➜ kubectl exec -it jump-machine -- /usr/local/bin/redis-cli -c -h redis-cluster-host --scan --pattern "*the-key-pattern*" | xargs -L 1 echo

the-key-pattern-1
the-key-pattern-2
the-key-pattern-3
...
```

Hope someone can shed some light on it, thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe you should somehow allocate a pseudo tty like when invoking `ssh -t`...  In different cases [ [1](https://superuser.com/a/874887/257269), [2](https://superuser.com/a/1138728/257269)]  such behavior was attributable to the non-allocation of a pseudo tty...

Comment: Searching around [they propose](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/37471) `alias kubectl='winpty kubectl'`... so again in the same direction -- allocate a paseudo tty. I do not know the semantic of the command you are using, but you can try a workaround executing a `bash` (with a forced tty allocation) that executes your command(s).

Comment: Thanks, use `bash` get the same result.

Comment: What is a "mache"?

Comment: @snapshoe, a jump-machine is a pod inside k8s cluster that I can use it to connect to the aws redis cluster.

Comment: Yes, I know what a jump-machine is. I was asking what a "mache" is. Either a term I can't find online anywhere, or a misspelling.

Comment: Yes a typo. Thanks @snapshoe, I've corrected it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should remove the `kubectl` part after `xargs`, like this:

```
kubectl exec -it jump-machine -- bash -c '/usr/local/bin/redis-cli -c -h redis-cluster-host --scan --pattern "*the-key-pattern*" | xargs -i /usr/local/bin/redis-cli -c -h redis-cluster-host DEL {}'
```

### Notice

1. the single quote is critical
2. change the `xargs -L 1` to `xargs -i`, because `xargs -L 1` is for running on mac osx, and now the single quoted makes `xargs` be running on linux, so `-L` is not recognized
3. `{}` is critical, otherwise you'll get `(error) CROSSSLOT Keys in request don't hash to the same slot`

Comment: thanks for your reply, but it does not work. If I removed `kubectl` then it'll try to execute `redis-cli` on my local machine that will cause an error: 

`xargs: redis-cli: No such file or directory`

Comment: In that case, I suggest this:
`kubectl exec -it jump-machine '$( /usr/local/bin/redis-cli -c -h redis-cluster-host --scan --pattern "*the-key-pattern*" | xargs -L 1 /usr/local/bin/redis-cli -c -h redis-cluster-host -c DEL`)'

Comment: Thanks for your help! But I still can't get it work. It gave `OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"$( /usr/local/bin/redis-cli ... )\": stat $( /usr/local/bin/redis-cli ... ): no such file or directory": unknown
command terminated with exit code 126`

Comment: I used single quotes.

Comment: Sorry, just saw I forgot the double dash.

Comment: I mean the double dash before the command, like ` -- $( `.

Comment: The same. For example: `kubectl exec -it jump-machine -- '$( /usr/local/bin/redis-cli keys * )'` Gave the same error, too

Comment: Basically `kubectl` runs the same way `docker` does. As a final attempt, could you try this? `kubectl exec -it jump-machine bash -c '/usr/local/bin/redis-cli -c -h redis-cluster-host --scan --pattern "*the-key-pattern*" | xargs -L 1 /usr/local/bin/redis-cli -c -h redis-cluster-host -c DEL'`

Comment: I seem to have forgotten again the double dash before the command. If it fails, just type `-- bash -c '/usr/local.......` instead of `bash -c '/usr/local......`

Comment: Worked, thank you!

Comment: Glad it did; I learned something too, trying to figure this one out.